# Interface 'Throwable' not found when I migrate the table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I want to migrate table in Laravel Framework.

But when I migrate the table the following bug appears.

`artisan migrate`

[image: This is the bug]

I have tried all solutions in stackoverflow, but anything doesn't work.
In .env file, I have set all the values correctly. I checked that many times.
I also checked php version and composer version.
And added `"psr-0"` to composer.json and tried `composer dump-autoload`.
I did all ways which I can do.

If anyone have met this bug before, then Please tell me.

Comment: I have same issue. I struggled with google but I didn't get any proper answer. Someone said to add    "laracasts/generators": "dev-master" in composer.json but it's still not working!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `Throwable` is available in PHP 7, but not before.

Comment: I'm using 7.1.8. I checked it already.